# How to set ID using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm generating a page with lot of product, and for this, i need lot of  ID, and i did it using a server side (Python) so i send for every product its own `<div id='hello1'> test </div>`

Now because the user will dinamycaly set a value and see the result in the browser, i want to generate another `ID` , to this i've found `btoa("hello1")` so i generate another `ID`

So the question, how do i put `btoa("hello1")` in `<div>` ?

Edit:  what i want to generate is another `<div>` and not updating the first one.

```
<input id="{{str(product["avt"]["fto"])}}" > this will become  <input id="12232" > because it is special to Tornado Template
<span>New price :</span>
<span id=btoa({{str(produit["avt"]["fto"])}})> This  is where i use innerHTML </span>
```

as you can see, the  users will put a value and see it dynamically.

This will work from Python using:

```
<span id="{{base64.b64encode(str(produit["avt"]["fto"]))}}"></span>
```

but i if it can be done using Javascript, the server will be free for the half of the operations!

Comment: Show us how you are generating the div.

Comment: Aren't those templates processed on the server side with python? Are you creating any elements with JavaScript?

Comment: @bfavaretto only the `input`  elements, the `span` element should be generated using javascript so i can use `getElementById` in realtime

Comment: Question title was all I needed the answer to.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
var hello1 = document.getElementById('hello1');
hello1.id = btoa(hello1.id);
```

---

To further the example, say you wanted to get all elements with the class 'abc'. We can use `querySelectorAll()` to accomplish this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="abc"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.abc');

// Set their ids
for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++)
    abcElements[i].id = 'abc-' + i;
```

This will assign the ID `'abc-<index number>'` to each element. So it would come out like this:

```
<div class="abc" id="abc-0"></div>
<div class="abc" id="abc-1"></div>
```

---

To create an element and assign an `id` we can use `document.createElement()` and then `appendChild()`.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'hello1';

var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(div);
```

---

**Update**

You can set the `id` on your element like this if your script is in your HTML file.

```
<input id="{{str(product["avt"]["fto"])}}" >
<span>New price :</span>
<span class="assign-me">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = document.getElementsByClassName('assign-me')[0];
    s.id = btoa({{str(produit["avt"]["fto"])}});
</script>
```

Your requirements still aren't 100% clear though.

Comment: What do you mean? That's how you set an `id`. Get the `element` and then use `element.id`

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp another one ?? what another way do you expect? this is the simplest and standard one

Comment: but the element has no id in the beginning, how do the browser know where to put the new generated one?

Comment: @DanielImms I think he means create a new div and assign ID.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev that's what i mean, i modified the question

Comment: But `id="{{str(produit["avt"]["fto"])}}"` is not valid for an `id`. Do you want to set the id of the first element in JS too?

Comment: @DanielImms no this is special for Tornado Templates, and it gives another value when rendered

Comment: Why are you setting it with JavaScript if it can be accomplished server side?

Comment: @DanielImms the user will put a percentage, and sees the new price formatted, and this both need ID because i use `innerHTML` so in the `getElementById` i can get both of them

Comment: @DanielImms to free the server from calculation, and send  the half of the work to the client side

Comment: I think you're underestimating just how powerful computers are these days. A simply operation to calculate an `id` should be done by the server if possible.

Comment: @DanielImms so it seems i'll go using Python, i've updated the question, look how it gets using python, if a client has a page of 10 products, then if i could use javascript then i will make only 10 operation, not 20 :(

Comment: @DanielImms so the javascript code here will only affect one element? because if there are 2 products it will get 2 same classes?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp I missed `[0]` at the end, that will select the first one. You can return without `[0]` to get an array and then iterate over it.

Comment: @DanielImms now i get it! thank you for helping me :)